# iOS: why i need to use antire mixpanel sdk to just tracking the event?

Tags: ios, mixpanel

> I integrated the mixpanel iOS sdk with my ios app.  It's working fine
>   but my  question is this, for just track the events why i need the
>   storyboard and assets and all?. Does any one knows here what are all
>   the necessary files that is enough to track the events?. The thing is, why i need to keep unused files in my project?.

Any help that might be really appreciated.

Comment: I want this to as I don't want all the features, I want a very light weight analytics in my app. Maybe best to use the HTTP api directly? Anyone got some code for that in IOS?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a cut down version of MixPanel for iOS that uses the MixPanel spec.

You can download it, and a demo app from my github page:
https://github.com/peterept/mixpanellite

The crux of the code is:

```
+(void)track:(NSString*)event properties:(NSDictionary*)properties {

  NSMutableDictionary *allProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[mixpanellite distinctIdentifier],@"distinct_id", MIXPANELLITE_TOKEN, @"token", nil];
  if (properties != nil) {
    [allProperties addEntriesFromDictionary:properties];
  }
  NSMutableDictionary *eventDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:event,@"event", allProperties, @"properties", nil];

  NSError *error = nil;
  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:eventDict options:0 error:&error];
  if (error == nil)
  {
    NSLog(@"[MIXPANELLITE] %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    NSString *urlTemplate = @"http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=%@";
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlTemplate, [jsonData mp_base64EncodedString]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:nil];
  }
}
```

The only dependency is Matt Gallagher's excellent NSData Base64 category.